# Cant find Google Market Licensing package in SDK Manager

Tags: java, android, android-lvl

I am going according to this [Setting Up the Development Environment](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html) and in the Downloading LVL section it says "Launch the Android SDK Manager and then select the Google Market Licensing package". When I launch my SDK and it has finished loading repositories, then it does not show the Google Market Licensing app. Help!

It does show Google Play Licensing Library though but the instructions on Google website clearly mentions Google Market Licensing package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would appear that the name has changed to "Google Play Licensing Library" in the SDK Manager.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!!! Why wouldnt Google change the screenshot and text on the article? Seems so stupid.

Comment: Surprisingly *still* not fixed as of today 4+ years later, I've reported it, but there are so many outdated pages in the docs it's seeming like a waste of time at this point.

Answer (score 1):

the name has changed to "Google Play Licensing Library".
Open the Android SDK Manager and open the EXTRAS folder you can find the "Google Play Licensing Library"